# how to push a data with key of an array of objects without overwriting existing json data using node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have an object that looks like this :

```
{
  "mark": [
    {
     "id":1,
    "name": "mark",
      "age":26
    },
    {
       "id":2,
     "name": "mark",
      "age":25
    }
],
"jack": [
    {
        "id":1,
      "name": "jack",
      "age":26
     
    },
    {
        "id":2,
      "name": "jack",
      "age": 24,
      
    }
  ]
}
```

WHAT I GOT AS OUTPUT IF A NEW USER IS ADDED IT IS NOT APPENDED, BUT IT IS OVERWRITTEN OR CREATED AS A NEW OBJECT

```
{
     "mark": [
            {
             "id":1,
            "name": "mark",
              "age":26
            },
            {
               "id":2,
             "name": "mark",
              "age":25
            }
        ],
        "jack": [
            {
                "id":1,
              "name": "jack",
              "age":26
             
            },
            {
                "id":2,
              "name": "jack",
              "age": 24,
              
            }
          ],
 
        }   "Josh": [ 
            {
                "id":1,
              "name": "Josh",
              "age":26
             
            },
            {
                "id":2,
              "name": "Josh",
              "age": 24,
              
            }
          ]
```

***Expected***

if new person data arrives in my JSON File, that should be appended to the next array with key values of array of Objects,

like

```
     {
          "mark": [
            {
             "id":1,
            "name": "mark",
              "age":26
            },
            {
               "id":2,
             "name": "mark",
              "age":25
            }
        ],
        "jack": [
            {
                "id":1,
              "name": "jack",
              "age":26
             
            },
            {
                "id":2,
              "name": "jack",
              "age": 24,
              
            }
          ],
"Josh": [ 
            {
                "id":1,
              "name": "Josh",
              "age":26
             
            },
            {
                "id":2,
              "name": "Josh",
              "age": 24,
              
            }
          ]
        }
```

I've tried this method after reading the JSON file

```
var newObject = array.reduce(function (obj, value) {
  var key = `${value.name}`;
  if (obj[key] == null) obj[key] = [];

  obj[key].push(value);
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(newObject);

fs.appendFile("users.json", newObject, (err) => {
  res.send(JSON.stringify(newObject));
});
```

Comment: `appendFile` is the wrong approach. You can't append JSON data. You have to read the whole data, modify it and write the whole data to the file. JSON is too complex to be modified with such basic text editing functions.

Answer (score 4):

Like the advice already given, but using *async* fs i/o.

```
import { promises as fs } from 'fs';  // or require('fs').promises

// inside the OP's route
  const filename = 'users.json';
  try {
    const array = await fs.readFile(filename);

    // OP's code here
    // const newObject = array.reduce(...

    await fs.writeFile(filename, newObject);
    return res.send(JSON.stringify(newObject));

  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).send({ message: 'error' });
  }
```

Also note that all this is what a database does.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first read the data from the JSON and append the new object to the JSON data and then write it back to the file.

```
const data = fs.readFileSync('users.json');
.
.
fs.writeFileSync('users.json', {...data, ...newObject});
```

Comment: This seems the best solution as I do not see a way to make the original code work, i.e., appending text to a json file. +1

Comment: @jabaa It depends on the environment and the actions that are done before and after this process.

Comment: @jabaa Its the same thing without the callback hell.

Comment: @DanPhilipBejoy, the reason that the synchronous reads and writes are frowned upon is that the size of the file and the number of clients is unbounded. If they start backing up, the queue grows exponentially. This is a sort of hell more hellish than callbacks.  Use async to mitigate the load and the the fs-promise variants to mitigate the callbacks.

Comment: JavaScript is single threaded. The sync functions block the whole server.

Comment: Also note that `{...data, ...newObject}` should be just `newObject`, which is a superset of the input.